# Golang struct definition patterns

Tags: go

I'm currently playing with Go, was wondering what are the patterns for defining the data types. For example take the [Bencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) and representing it as a Go data structure.

[like in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bencode-0.6.0.0/docs/src/Data-BEncode.html#BEncode)

```
data BEncode = BInt Integer
         | BString L.ByteString
         | BList [BEncode]
         | BDict (Map String BEncode)
```

[in C, we can do something like this](https://dzone.com/articles/bencoding-parser-c)

```
struct Bencoding;

typedef struct ListNode {
    struct Bencoding *cargo;
    struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct DictNode {
    char *key;
    struct Bencoding *value;
    struct DictNode *next;
} DictNode;

typedef struct Bencoding {
    BType type;
    union {
        long long val;  // used when type == BInt
        ListNode *list; // used when type == BList
        char *str;      // used when type == BString
        DictNode *dict;
    } cargo; // data
} Bencoding;
```

what is the best way to define these kinds of data structures in Golang. Are there any patterns / good practices with Golang.

Comment: structs are the only object type in Go and they follow most of the same rules as in C. If you know enough to ask the question you should also know enough to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
type BEncodeType int

const (
    TypeBInt BEncodeType = iota
    TypeBString
    TypeBList
    TypeBDict
)

type BEncode interface {
    Type() BEncodeType
    Val() interface{}
}

type BInt int

func (n *BInt) Type() BEncodeType {
    return TypeBInt
}
func (n *BInt) Val() interface{} {
    return n
}

type BString string

func (n *BString) Type() BEncodeType {
    return TypeBString
}
func (n *BString) Val() interface{} {
    return n
}

type BList []BEncode

func (n *BList) Type() BEncodeType {
    return TypeBList
}
func (n *BList) Val() interface{} {
    return n
}

type BDict map[string]BEncode

func (n *BDict) Type() BEncodeType {
    return TypeBDict
}
func (n *BDict) Val() interface{} {
    return n
}
```